# How to get numpy to interpret object array slice as single array?

Tags: python, numpy

When you ask Numpy to make an array out of a collection including arbitrary objects, it will create an array of "object" type, which allows you to use index slicing across those objects, but since the object itself is unknown to numpy, you cannot index into the object in one go (even if that particular object **is** actually a numpy array).

However, if you slice into the object array to select the parts of the object array that are actually numpy arrays, it seems that numpy won't collapse that slice into a single numpy array, even with another call to `np.array()`. Here is a little example of what I mean:

```py
>>> aa = np.array([np.random.randn(3, 4), {'something': 'blah'}], dtype=object)
>>> aa.shape
(2,)
>>> np.array(aa[0:1])
array([array([[ 1.78237043, -0.61082005,  0.92160137,  0.58961677],
              [ 1.54183639, -0.43097464,  1.36213935, -1.2695875 ],
              [ 0.01431181, -0.62073519,  0.56267489, -0.46113538]])],
      dtype=object)
>>> np.array(aa[0:1]).shape # I want this to be (1, 3, 4)
(1,)
```

Is there any way to do this without a double copy (e.g. not like this: `np.array(aa[0:1].tolist())`)? Does an object array even allow you to do this without such a copy?

Comment: An object array is basically a less-performant, vanilla Python list with a vectorized API. It is an array of pointers to Py_Object structs. The types of those objects is opaque to the implementation.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, `.tolist()` is pretty cheap, since the array objects aren't being copied. It's just the underlying buffer of pointers

Comment: in general, you should consider carefully whether you want to be using numpy at all if you are using `dtype=object` arrays

Comment: I didn't realise (or didn't consider) that the objects were referenced as-is by numpy. So, `.tolist()` is much cheaper than I thought. I just wanted multidimensional vectorised indexing.

Comment: Note that the `tolist()` part is cheap, but the subsequent `array` call has to copy data. A data copy will be unavoidable for any object array with multiple subarrays, since those subarrays have data buffers at completely unrelated locations with completely unrelated lifetimes. You could write no-copy special-case handling for a slice with a single subarray, but if you know you're slicing out a single subarray, you probably shouldn't use a slice in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) to combine the object-type array to a normal `ndarray`:

```
>>> aa = np.array([np.random.randn(3, 4), {'something': 'blah'}], dtype=object)
>>> aa
array([array([[-6.36267204e-01,  8.95707498e-02,  1.09275216e+00,
               -3.70594544e-01],
              [ 8.32865823e-01, -6.53876690e-01,  1.21000457e+00,
                1.22046398e+00],
              [-5.30262118e-01,  1.17934947e-04,  4.45156002e-01,
               -6.61549444e-02]])                                ,
       {'something': 'blah'}], dtype=object)
>>> np.stack(aa[0:1])
array([[[-6.36267204e-01,  8.95707498e-02,  1.09275216e+00,
         -3.70594544e-01],
        [ 8.32865823e-01, -6.53876690e-01,  1.21000457e+00,
          1.22046398e+00],
        [-5.30262118e-01,  1.17934947e-04,  4.45156002e-01,
         -6.61549444e-02]]])
>>> np.stack(aa[0:1]).shape
(1, 3, 4)
```

This also works with multiple ndarrays in your object-array, as long as they have compatible sizes.

Internally, this just treats the object-array as a sequence and [iterates over it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.0/numpy/core/shape_base.py#L458). I'm not sure if it has a significant performance benefit over your solution with `np.array(aa[0:1].tolist())`.